# How can I prevent .Net from escaping provided Url in System.Web.HttpRequest?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, escaping, httprequest

When I try to browse this Url ([http://localhost:21664/home/test/تست](http://localhost:21664/home/test/%D8%AA%D8%B3%D8%AA)) in browser, the Url in HttpRequest contains in HttpContext that is created in MVC Pipeline is not escaped.

[image: The Url Is Not Escaped]

But when I try to create an HttpRequest object manually with the same Non-English characters in it as below:

```
var httpRequest = new HttpRequest(string.Empty, "http://localhost:41111/تست/blahblah", string.Empty);
```

.Net changes (escape) the Url and the result is like this:

[image: Manually created HttpRequest]

I want to know what is the difference between creating HttpRequest manually and the HttpRequest that is in CurrentContext.

Comment: https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#url-writing

Comment: Are the urls equivalent?  If you try to visit the escaped url do you end up at the same url?

Comment: @Neil yes they are completely equivalent, when I try to browse the escaped Url in for example Chrome, The url changes to the unescaped one.

Comment: I don't know the definitive answer, but I would guess that it's been escaped because it has to be to be a representable url.  Why do you think it is a problem?

Comment: @Neil you're right, I updated my question and appended more description to it.